# Apache Camel CXF

Tags: java, soap, apache-camel

Camel Configuration was working fine with v 2.13.4. After migrating to v 2.15.1 I am getting following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/apache/camel/component/cxf/spring/NamespaceHandler, offset=6
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/apache/camel/component/cxf/spring/NamespaceHandler, offset=6
```

In camel configuration I am using following schemas:

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
            xsi:schemaLocation="
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
               http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
               http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">

<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="soapProxy"
            address="/data" endpointName="s:dataManagementSOAP"
            serviceName="s:dataManagement" 
            wsdlURL="/path/to/proxy.wsdl"
            xmlns:s="http://www.test.com/integration/referencedata" />
    ......
    bean definitions
    .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be running your application on Java 6.0, and Apache Camel has [dropped support of Java 6.0 since 2.14.0](http://camel.apache.org/camel-2140-release.html) (see "Important changes to consider when upgrading" section)

Recompiling camel in Java 6.0 wont be feasible, I believe your options are either to upgrade to Java 7.0 or to downgrade Camel to a version pre 2.14.0

Comment: Have to downgrade Camel to a version pre 2.14.0